# what to do when a Theme uses a custom post type slug that conflicts with a plugin?

Tags: slug

I'm a designer not a developer.

A client is using a free 3rd party Wordpress theme, and when The Events Calendar is installed, the default events calendar does not load @ [/events](http://www.banksia.wa.edu.au/events).

The body tag looks correct:

`<body class="archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-tribe_events logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support tribe-filter-live events-gridview events-archive tribe-events-style-full tribe-events-style-theme tribe-theme-peachclub-theme page-template-page-php singular" >`

A working events calendar page on another website has a body tag of:

`<body class="archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-tribe_events tribe-filter-live events-gridview events-archive tribe-events-style-full tribe-events-style-theme tribe-theme-parent-ManiaFramework tribe-theme-child-AutoRacing page-template-page-php singular">`

Additionally, if I visit Dashboard > Events > Settings, I don't see any settings:

[image]

If I change the theme to TwentyFifteen, the calendar shows at `/events`, and the Events settings page shows.

I've asked the plugin author for help, but they say the theme is not compatible with The Events Calendar.

I'm wondering if this is because the theme and the plugin conflict over slugs in some way?

How would I test that the theme uses perhaps custom post type slugs used by The Events Calendar?

I tried deactivting The Events Calendar, and adding the following code in my theme's `functions.php`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'unregister_post_type' ) ) :
function unregister_post_type() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    if ( isset( $wp_post_types[ 'event' ] ) ) {
        unset( $wp_post_types[ 'event' ] );
        return true;
    }
    if ( isset( $wp_post_types[ 'events' ] ) ) {
        unset( $wp_post_types[ 'events' ] );
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}
endif;

add_action('init', 'unregister_post_type');
```

After uploading `functions.php`, and reloading the home page, `/events` produced a 404, which I thought was promising, but reactivating The Events Calendar did not make the calendar load @ `/events`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know, The Events Calendar doesn't use 'event' or 'events' as the post type.  I believe they use 'tribe_events' as their post type.

Comment: Have you enabled WP-DEBUG https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress? If so, you should see if you receive any errors when you visit the Events settings page

Answer (score 1):

Disable the WordPress event plugin.

Use following code in functions.php to find your theme has events function.

```
if ( post_type_exists( 'events' ) ) {
       echo 'the Event post type exists';
}else{
       echo 'the Event post type does not exists';
}
```

1. If you find theme has events custom post type, find where your theme register the custom post type. Most probably it is functions.php. Check functions.php has `register_post_type( 'events', $args );` . $args variable may be has different name. So find where is locating `register_post_type( 'events',` using IDE or pressing ctrl+f5.
2. If you found it in functions.php create a child theme. Just a google search, you can find how to create a child theme even you are not a WordPress developer. It is not hard.
3. Then copied functions.php file to child theme. Then remove the `register_post_type( 'events', $args );` parts from it.

Comment: Actually this wont work, because child `functions.php` file is loaded on top of parent `functions.php` file (it is not overrided). From Codex: "Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)"

Comment: Thanks Sandun. I found: `events` & `event` post type do not exist. Where to from here?

Comment: Hello @Sandun? Are you able to assist?

Answer (score 0):

Ask the theme developer or the plugin developer to prefix their custom post type. If you can't wait do it yourself by starting with the code that's smaller I am thinking the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix what you don't know is broken.

**View the Error Logs**

Do you have accesss to their webhost?

It's likely available through cPanel. See what type of errors are displaying. It could be a similarly named PHP function or something else causing the issue.

**Confirm Post Type Name Collision**

If you have access to the database, it's easy to see if the post types conflict or not.

1. Login to your database => cPanel => phpMyAdmin
2. Open the correct database and select the wp_posts table
3. View the contents and scroll to the right until you see the `post_type` column
4. Look to see if there are multiple different post types

[image: wordpress posts table post type]